# Arbitrary values returned by class member functions

Tags: c++, class, constructor, member-functions

I'm working on a project composed of a lot of `.cxx` files. Now I want to edit a class adding some variables and functions (which are the line commented in the following)

```
#ifndef TN_LORENTZCHARGEVECTOR_
#define TN_LORENTZCHARGEVECTOR_
#include<iostream>
#include <TLorentzVector.h>

#include "common/Helpers.h"

class LorentzChargeVector : public TLorentzVector
{
public:
    inline LorentzChargeVector()
        : TLorentzVector(),
          _charge(0) {}

    inline LorentzChargeVector(const TLorentzVector &vec,
                               float charge)
        : TLorentzVector(vec),
          _charge(charge) {}

    inline LorentzChargeVector(const LorentzChargeVector &v)
        : TLorentzVector(v),
          _charge(v.Charge()) {}

    inline float Charge() const { return _charge; }
    inline void SetCharge(float charge) { _charge = charge; }
/*
    inline float Trkd0() {std::cout << "fnction" << _trkd0 << std::endl;return _trkd0;}
    inline void SetTrkd0(float trkd0) {std::cout << '\t' << trkd0 << std::endl; _trkd0 = trkd0;std::cout << '\t' << _trkd0 << std::endl;}

    inline float Trkd0sig() {return _trkd0sig;}
    inline void SetTrkd0sig(float trkd0sig) {_trkd0sig = trkd0sig;}

    inline float Trkz0() {return _trkz0;}
    inline void SetTrkz0(float trkz0) {_trkz0 = trkz0;}

    inline float Trkz0sintheta() {return _trkz0sintheta;}
    inline void SetTrkz0sintheta(float trkz0sintheta) {_trkz0sintheta = trkz0sintheta;}
*/
    inline LorentzChargeVector &operator=(const LorentzChargeVector &q)
    {
        TLorentzVector::operator=(q);
        _charge = q.Charge();
        return *this;
    }

    inline LorentzChargeVector operator+(const LorentzChargeVector &q) const
    {
        return LorentzChargeVector(TLorentzVector::operator+(q), _charge + q.Charge());
    }

    inline LorentzChargeVector &operator+=(const LorentzChargeVector &q)
    {
        TLorentzVector::operator+=(q);
        _charge += q.Charge();
        return *this;
    }

    inline LorentzChargeVector operator-(const LorentzChargeVector &q) const
    {
        return LorentzChargeVector(TLorentzVector::operator-(q), _charge - q.Charge());
    }

    inline LorentzChargeVector &operator-=(const LorentzChargeVector &q)
    {
        TLorentzVector::operator-=(q);
        _charge -= q.Charge();
        return *this;
    }

    inline LorentzChargeVector operator-() const
    {
        return LorentzChargeVector(TLorentzVector::operator-(), -_charge);
    }

    inline Bool_t operator==(const LorentzChargeVector &q) const
    {
        return (Vect() == q.Vect() && T() == q.T() && Charge() == q.Charge());
    }

    inline Bool_t operator!=(const LorentzChargeVector &q) const
    {
        return (Vect() != q.Vect() || T() != q.T() || Charge() != q.Charge());
    }

    // Print
    inline void Print(Option_t *option="") const override
    {
        UNUSED(option)

        Printf("(x,y,z,t)=(%f,%f,%f,%f) (P,eta,phi,E)=(%f,%f,%f,%f) charge=%f",
               X(), Y(), Z(), E(),
               P(), Eta(), Phi(), E(), _charge);
    }


private:
    float _charge;
//    float _trkd0;
//    float _trkd0sig;
//    float _trkz0;
//    float _trkz0sintheta;

    ClassDefOverride(LorentzChargeVector, 1);
};

#endif // TN_LORENTZCHARGEVECTOR_
```

My problems here are given by the functions which return the values. The functions that set the value (`SetTrkd0` ecc.) work fine. Instead, the functions that return a value (`Trkd0`, `Trkd0sig` ecc.) give me an arbitrary value.

I think that the error is due to the *constructors*, which are not edited to the new variables.

Comment: All those uses of `inline` are completely pointless.

Comment: If you don't initialize your class member variables you will get a garbage value. The only variable you initialize in your constructor is `_charge`.

Comment: Expanding/explaining Neil's comment: Functions fully defined within the body of a class are automatically `inline`.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor need to explicitly initialize all members otherwise it will store indeterminate values which you perceive as garbage(arbitrary values). In your case `_trkd0`, `_trkd0sig` ,`_trkz0`, `_trkz0sintheta`are left uninitialized.

Also, please consider separating implementation and declaration of class. It may allow you to change the implementation independently of the interface and this may be easier when dealing with change requirements like in your case.